# Sum all available values returned from a referenced cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

=VLOOKUP brings out the first value it finds. However, my data has more than one matches and would like to add them up rather than just take the first value.
 
 
Issue encountered with =SUMIFs is that it doesn't let me use a cell reference. It requires I include a criteria within it's formula but this will be challenging since I have more than 500 cells to reference.
 
Is there anyway to lookup a cell and sum up all values returned?

*currently using office 365*

Comment: Please clarify the problem you have. Show us sample data and the SUMIF you are trying that seems to give you an error

Comment: And show us the ```VLOOKUP```,  if it relates to which values you want to add.

Comment: Currently replying on phone. Will update when home on PC. Many thanks

Comment: Hello, I haven't been able to access data since I posted this as I am away. Will update as soon as possible and you guys can get back to me whenever you can. Many thanks.

Comment: You'd better share a sample with the result that you expect with us. This action could help us understand your issue better. In addition, please check whether "[Sumproduct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)" function is helpful

Comment: In what way will SUMIFS not let you use a cell reference? It is not clear what you want but usually SUMIFS is used like this: =SUMIFS(Add these up, (when) These corresponding cells, contain this value, (and when) these other cells, contain this value). If you need an OR in there just add SUMIFS's together (or add SUMIFs together).

Answer (score 0):

You wander about some and contradict yourself somewhat in describing what is desired. But the first line, referring to `VLOOKUP()` makes it clear you want only some of the data to be summed. So there is a column of data for the comparison and you want some data associated with it from the same rows that include the lookup values that are found. So, say data in columns a and B and in rows 1 through 10.

The old school way was to do a comparison involving the lookup column. It would compare the entire column to the lookup value and return an array of TRUE/FALSE's. You can turn those into 1's and 0's by multiplying that result by 1. Or any other value which is helpful here. For the multiplying value, you use the return column (column B in my example range):  just an array of those values.

So the fact of multiplication changes those TRUE/FALSE's that the lookup array returned to numbers, 1's and 0"s. When you multiply them by the entire second column's values, you get an array with 0's anywhere the first array had FALSE's and the actual values from the return column since 1*(any value) = (any value).

Now you have an array with non-0's where your lookup column matched the lookup value and 0's for all other elements in it. This is where `SUM()` comes in. It will sum those up and, of course, those 0's (items that did not match the lookup value) will not add anything to the sum — only those values from matching rows in the lookup column will contribute.

So that is your sum of the values from the matches.

Given the range I mentioned at the start, A1:B10, it would look like this:

```
=SUM(B1:B10*(A1:A10="A"))
```

For a more complicated need, perhaps one in which you want, perhaps, the sum of only those returns that are >3, you just add a multiplying term that does THAT comparison:

```
=SUM(B1:B10*(A1:A10="A")*(B1:B10>=3))
```

A "modern" approach for this could use `FILTER()` instead of the two ranges:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B10,A1:A10="a"))
```

Not precisely "simpler"... but easier for the average user to grasp. Notice, though, that in it you are doing something it isn't usually used for and that is returning values from one column but using a comparison for a different column. Largely it would return a whole table of results based upon some comparison/s using one or some of its columns. This use is more like the way `XLOOKUP()` lets you use unrelated columns and in fact, its criteria column (the `A1:A10="a"` part) could be ANY set of data that both contains as many items as the source column/s does and you can get Excel to take as a range.

Bringing me to the last point. I sort of get the impression from what you say that the lookup material is NOT all in a single column, that it might be willy-nilly-ed all over the place. That comes from your claim `SUMIFS()` won't take a range for building a criterion when of course, it certainly will.

The impression is that you are trying to give it a range of various cells.

Well, that won't work. BUT, you can build that range using any Excel technique suitable:  cells or Named Ranges, say, then refer to that creation instead of the willy-nilly cells dotted all over the place.

What do I mean? Simple version might be you want three random cells to be the range. They could be perhaps E20, G3, and B244. Pick a place out of the way, even another sheet, and enter in a cell `=E20` and in the next cell (downward, usually) `=G3` and finally, in the next cell from that `B244`. Perhaps you started with cell AHC1 and have used AHC1:AHC3. So when you need the range, you enter `AHC1:AHC3` (or even `AHC1#` if a `SPILL` function will work in your situation). So while you cannot directly enter that `E20, G3, B244` range, you CAN still use it. Or maybe you enter that into a Named Range. However you get Excel to do it, you get the end result.